# Comparing dates to check for old files

Tags: python, time, comparison, filemtime

I want to check if a file is older than a certain amount of time (e.g. 2 days).

I managed to get the file creation time in such a way:

```
>>> import os.path, time
>>> fileCreation = os.path.getctime(filePath)
>>> time.ctime(os.path.getctime(filePath))
'Mon Aug 22 14:20:38 2011'
```

How can I now check if this is older than 2 days?

I work under Linux, but a cross platform solution would be better. Cheers!

Comment: What is `file` in a 3rd line?

Comment: corruption which i just removed

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
now = time.time()
twodays_ago = now - 60*60*24*2 # Number of seconds in two days
if fileCreation < twodays_ago:
    print "File is more than two days old"
```

Comment: +1 i knew it was quite easy... but i was a bit blocket by data types... thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I believe it would be cleaner to use timedelta (ref.: Eduardo's answer).

Answer (score 31):

I know, it is an old question. But I was looking for something similar and came up with this alternative solution:

```
from os import path
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

two_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)
filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(file_path))

if filetime < two_days_ago:
  print "File is more than two days old."
```

Comment: You can skip the conversion to and from the string representation: filetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(path.getctime(file))

Comment: @ErikForsberg, that is nicer! Updated it. Thanks!